# Find and Replace symbol for whole project intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, replace, find, intellij-14

In **IntelliJ IDEA**, is there an option to find and replace a symbol for whole project with on time operation?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has extensive support for refactoring, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/refactoring-source-code.html What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PREdDtOoh1Q

Answer (score 158, accepted):

**EDIT:**

**Here is the** [Visual representation](https://youtu.be/PREdDtOoh1Q) **for better understanding.**

Replacing a piece of text in all the files within the specified path do one of the following:

- On the main menu, choose Edit | Find | Replace in Path
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

You can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

And if you are using [Eclipse keymap for IntelliJ](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Configure+Keymap) then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: For my question it should be Ctrl+Shift+R right? :))

Comment: **Ctrl+Shift+R** is the answer. Then you click *Replace* in the *Replace in Path* dialog box. But here's the bizarre thing: nothing gets replaced! The dialog box closes and a window opens at the bottom part of the screen showing occurrences. Then you need to click the *Replace All* button in that window. Then a new dialog box pops up where you need to click the *Replace* button yet again. **Inefficient UI, poor Ux**.

Comment: `cmd+r` for Mac users

Comment: ctrl+shift+h here using the vscode keymap

Answer (score 12):

### Windows/Linux Shortcut

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

### MacOS Shortcut

<kbd>shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>command ⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

### Common Shortcut

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> twice and type `Replace in Path`

You get an option to apply file mask, scope, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For me, worked:

**Ctrl + H** - To replace all occurrences in a specific file

**Ctrl + Shift + H** - To replace all occurrences in all files

But I remember I have configured my key map in VSCode style.
Also, I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, but it looks unrelated.