# Find and Replace in entire project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm sure this is not a difficult question to answer. 
I'm able to replace a specific word or regex expression within a file in Android Studio.

But, I can't seem to know how to do it project wide.

I'm clicking ctrl-R and click on replaceAll button, but it only changes within the current file.

Any idea how to do the same ***but in the entire project***.

Answer (score 6):

Click CTRL+SHIFT+R

This will do a whole project, or folder, or scope replacement.

You can click on any folder on the left window, and do CTRL+SHIFT+R this will confine the replacement to that folder.

You can also do CTRL+SHIFT+F to do a global search without the replacement.

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ and shares all default shortcuts, if you can't find an AndroidStudio answer, its ok to search for Intellij also:

[Find and Replace symbol for whole project intellij? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444457/413127](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444457/413127)

Comment: Thanks man.. now I can go and migrate to AndroidX faster @Blundell

Comment: You know there's a menu option for that **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio

Comment: yes I know, but after trying that I still have to delete the old imports that reference the support library.. I'm manually changing them to the AndroidX equivalents. But I'm having trouble with androidx.leanback.preference.LeanbackPreferenceDialogFragment  .  Android studio is telling me is not found? any ideas? @Blundell

Comment: docs say its deprecated, so might no longer be in the version you have. Try `LeanbackPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat`